# how to manage pictures just with front-end?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a website for an artist, which contains 40 photos and will add more from time to time.
I've only used the front-end with react js, should I add the back-end just for the photos? And use a solution like cloudinary to store these photos and manage them with the back-end?
from how many photos or storage size would it be preferable to add the back-end?
because I've read that storing photos on the front-end would slow down loading and that it's not a good practice.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cloudinary you can send images directly from the frontend.  Here is an example that uses `react-cloudinary-upload-widget` to make a simple photo upload widget. Here is the documentation for `react-cloudinary-upload-widget` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cloudinary-upload-widget

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { CloudinaryContext, Image } from 'cloudinary-react'
import { WidgetLoader, Widget } from 'react-cloudinary-upload-widget'

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('')

  const handleUpload = (result) => {
    setImage(result.info.url)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <WidgetLoader />
      <Widget
        sources={['local', 'camera']} 
        resourceType={'image'} 
        cloudName={'cloudName1'} 
        uploadPreset={'preset1'} 
        buttonText={'Open'} 
        onSuccess={handleUpload}
      />
      <CloudinaryContext cloudName='cloudName1'>
        {image && <Image publicId={image} />}
      </CloudinaryContext>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

You can add the image to `state` using the `onSuccess` property on the `react-cloudinary-upload-widget` Widget or you could fetch the images again from the cloudinary API.

If you want you could use the more generic upload-widget from Cloudinary.  It might require a bit more effort to get working.  See the documentation: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget